# HTML Forms: The value attribute doesn't change what's sent to php

Tags: php, html, forms

so I'm having problems with forms sending data to my php script.

My html is:

```
<form method="get" action="form.php">
    <select name="course">
        <option value"COMM1">COMM1111</option>
        <option value"COMM2">COMM2222</option>
        <option value"COMM3">COMM3333</option>
        <option value"COMM4">COMM4444</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

What's sent to form.php when I do

```
$_GET['course']
```

is the inner text of the chosen option.

So choosing COMM1111 gives me COMM1111 instead of COMM1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your option tag you forgot your equal sign for value

```
<option value = "COMM1">COMM1111</option>
```

Comment: I like how my answer was first but your answer goes to the top and gets marked as right, no worries just SO being SO :D

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the = sign in your HTML for the value of the options.

Consider the following code which produces the values you are looking for ::

**HTML:**

```
<form method="get">
    <select name="course">
        <option value="COMM1">COMM1111</option>
        <option value="COMM2">COMM2222</option>
        <option value="COMM3">COMM3333</option>
        <option value="COMM4">COMM4444</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_GET)){
        print_r($_GET);
    }
?>
```